# Multi part form-data image upload using cordova-file-transfer plugin in ios fails

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, multipartform-data, file-transfer

I have to upload an image to server using multi-part image upload from my ionic project. Here is my code,

```
$scope.uploadImage = function(imageUrl) {
      var fileName = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      var json=  {
        "id":123,
        "name" :fileName
      }
      var fileUploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
     fileUploadOptions.fileKey="file";
     fileUploadOptions.fileName = fileName;
     fileUploadOptions.params = {
       json : json
     };
     fileUploadOptions.mimeType="image/jpeg";
     var URL = 'http://192.168.43.7:8080/services/uploadImage'
     var encodedURI = encodeURI(URL);
     console.log('fileUploadOptions : ',fileUploadOptions);
     var ft = new FileTransfer();
     ft.upload(imageUrl, encodedURI, onSuccess, onError, fileUploadOptions, false);

     function onSuccess(response){
      console.log('file uploaded: ',response);
     }
     function onError(error){
       console.log('upload failed',error);
     }
   }
```

I am using the following plugins

`cordova-plugin-file` 
`cordova-plugin-file-transfer` 
`cordova-plugin-camera`

My image capture code is

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {

            var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: 1,
                allowEdit: false,
                encodingType: 0,
                targetWidth: 1280,
                targetHeight: 720,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                direction: 1,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            };

            var cameraSuccess = function(imageData) {
                onPhotoURISuccess(imageData);

                function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
                    createFileEntry(imageURI);
                }

                function createFileEntry(imageURI) {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, copyPhoto, fail);
                }

                function copyPhoto(fileEntry) {
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
                        fileSys.root.getDirectory("photos", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(dir) {
                            var fileName = 12 + "_" + 56 + "_" + 67 + ".jpg";
                            fileEntry.copyTo(dir, fileName, onCopySuccess, fail);
                        }, fail);
                    }, fail);
                }

                function onCopySuccess(entry) {
                    console.log('Full path: ', JSON.stringify(entry));
                    var path = entry.toURL();
                    $scope.imageUrl = path;
                    console.log('imageUrl: ',$scope.imageUrl);

                }

                function fail(error) {
                    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
                    var cause = "";
                    if (error.code == 20) {
                        cause = "Camera permission denied"
                    }

                }

            }

            var cameraError = function(error) {
                console.log('camera error: ', error);
            }
            navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, options);



        }
```

I am passing the `$scope.imageUrl` variable to upload function.

The code works fine in android devices.
But iOS, the upload fails.

I am getting

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

error in my server console.

In my device console I am getting the following error,

**upload failed** 
body: "An error has occurred. Please contact system administrator."
code: 3
exception: null
http_status: 500
source: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8C4518AC-5606-4806-A8D2-216125EFE725/Documents/photos/12_56_57.jpg"
target: "http://192.168.43.7:8080/services/uploadImage"

The message in the body of the error is from my server.
As per the error I get from server, I came to know that, the JSON part is not getting uploaded to server. I tried to recreate the same issue with postman without sending the JSON object. I got the same error.

Do anyone know what is the issue ? Why only in iOS device this issue is there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> params: A set of optional key/value pairs to pass in the HTTP request. (Object, key/value - DOMString)

Try using `fileUploadOptions.params = { json : JSON.stringify(json) }` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.. You fixed the issue which troubled me for last 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageUrI="file:///storage/emulated/0/newfile.csv";
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg/csv";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "http://fileupload/admin/add_image_my.php",
function (result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
},
function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}, options);
```